# Scriptaculous Sortable.create - Can't hook the dragged element

Tags: prototypejs, jquery-ui-sortable, scriptaculous

When using `Sortable.create` I can't seem to get the element that is being dragged. Does Sciptaculous not fully implement all Draggable and Droppable features when you use sortable?

Given:

```
Sortable.create("sortArea", {scroll:window, onChange:orderLi});

function orderLi(){
    console.log(this.draggables.each(function(e){if(e.dragging==true){return e};}));
}
```

My console always shows all the array of draggables. How do I only grab the one that is being dragged?

Answer (score 0):

The onChange function actually gets a handle to the element passed in.

```
Sortable.create("sortArea", {scroll:window, onChange:orderLi});

function orderLi(elementBeingDragged){
  console.log(elementBeingDragged);
}
```

Comment: When I do that it reports the container in the console not the element I'm dragging.